# R extract elements from string based on position of spaces

Tags: r, split

I have a dataframe that consists of user metadata based on the date of last modification.

The dataframe looks like this -

```
dataframe=data.frame(Last_Modified=c("Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM",
                                 "Veronika White  10/01/1996 13:12:00 AM",
                                 "Vincent Michaels  01/03/2008 12:01:00 PM"))
```

**Desired Output**

I would like to extract the name, the date and the time and store them in three separate columns called `Name`, `Date` & `Time`.

For example, the first row `"Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM"` would be decomposed into **three additional columns** with `Name` as `Peter Jones`, `Date` as `11/02/1992` and `Time` as `03:50:02 PM`. And the same for the remaining rows.

**My Attempt**

I am trying to use the spaces that separate each entity as a means of splitting.
Based on a previous post, I tried using variations of the line below. But this is not returning me the desired output.

```
sub("^\\S+\\s+", '', dataframe$Last_Modified)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if the overall format of each entry is the same, you can use the strsplit command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data:

```
df1 = data.frame(Last_Modified=c("Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM",
                                     "Veronika White  10/01/1996 13:12:00 AM",
                                     "Vincent Michaels  01/03/2008 12:01:00 PM"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

code:

```
ans <- strsplit(df1$Last_Modified, "\\s+(?=\\d)", perl = T)

ans <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, ans), stringsAsFactors = F)
names(ans) <- c("Name", "Date", "Time")
```

result:

```
#              Name       Date        Time
#1      Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM
#2   Veronika White 10/01/1996 13:12:00 AM
#3 Vincent Michaels 01/03/2008 12:01:00 PM
```

---

Please note:

- You name your dataframe dataframe. Don't use reserved language keywords as variable names
- With your example data, characters are converted to factors: [READ THIS](https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/)
- `\\s+(?=\\d)` pattern uses a positive look ahead. Read and learn about positive look ahead in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option using `sub`:

```
df = data.frame(Last_Modified=c("Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM",
                                "Veronika White  10/01/1996 13:12:00 AM",
                                "Vincent Michaels  01/03/2008 12:01:00 PM"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$Name <- sub("(.*?)(?= \\d).*", "\\1", df$Last_Modified, perl=TRUE)
df$Date <- sub(".*(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}).*", "\\1", df$Last_Modified, perl=TRUE)
df$Time <- sub(".*(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} (?:AM|PM))", "\\1", df$Last_Modified, perl=TRUE)
df[c("Name", "Date", "Time")]

               Name       Date        Time
1       Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM
2   Veronika White  10/01/1996 13:12:00 AM
3 Vincent Michaels  01/03/2008 12:01:00 PM
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `stringi` package with some regex:

```
library(stringi)

dataframe=data.frame(Last_Modified=c("Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM",
                                     "Veronika White  10/01/1996 13:12:00 AM",
                                     "Vincent Michaels  01/03/2008 12:01:00 PM"))


name_part <- stri_match_last_regex(dataframe$Last_Modified, pattern = "^[A-Za-z ]*\\d")
dataframe$Name <- lapply(name_part, function(x) { trimws(stri_sub(x, 1, length = nchar(x) - 2))})
dataframe$Date <- stri_match_last_regex(dataframe$Last_Modified, pattern = "\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d")
dataframe$Time <- stri_match_last_regex(dataframe$Last_Modified, pattern = "\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d [AP]M")

dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace spaces followed by digit with comma followed by that same digit and then use `read.table` with `sep=","` :

```
read.table(text = gsub(" +(\\d)", ",\\1", dataframe[[1]]), 
 sep = ",", col.names = c("Name", "Date", "Time"), as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
              Name       Date        Time
1      Peter Jones 11/02/1992 03:50:02 PM
2   Veronika White 10/01/1996 13:12:00 AM
3 Vincent Michaels 01/03/2008 12:01:00 PM
```